# ASP.net Website want debug to == false on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

**Have tried adding this to web.config**

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
</compilation>
```

**but website still executes code in #if DEBUG when it shouldn't**

*Wierdly the inline statement <% #if DEBUG %> on aspx files works but require also for .cs code.

NB development and live website on same box

Comment: Is this a Web Site or Web Application project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#if` directives in backend `.cs` files are handled by the C# compiler, not ASP.Net.
Set your project to the Release configuration so that that symbol is not defined when compiling the DLL in VS.

Answer (score 0):

`compilation debug` element is not the same thing as DEBUG preprocessor directive.
You need to re-compile your website in Release mode.

> What about binaries compiled with debug symbols?
>
> One scenario that several people find very useful is to
>   compile/pre-compile an application or associated class libraries with
>   debug symbols so that more detailed stack trace and line error
>   messages can be retrieved from it when errors occur.
>
> The good news is that you can do this without having the have the
>    switch enabled in production. 
>   Specifically, you can use either a web deployment project or a web
>   application project to pre-compile the code for your site with debug
>   symbols, and then change the  switch to
>   false right before you deploy the application on the server.
>
> The debug symbols and metadata in the compiled assemblies will
>   increase the memory footprint of the application, but this can
>   sometimes be an ok trade-off for more detailed error messages.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/11/Don_1920_t-run-production-ASP.NET-Applications-with-debug_3D001D20_true_1D20_-enabled.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the compile configuration to release as well. In Visual Studio, Build Menu > Configuration Manager and make sure "Release" is selected for all your assemblies, and/or is the active solution configuration.